# How can I change a numeric input field with the mouse or touch?

Tags: javascript, html, input, touch, usability

I would like to create an input field where you can click/touch into and then move up or down to change the value of the field until you release the mouse/finger.

This should work in recent browsers and on Android and iPhones.

Comment: i tried the jquery slider ui, but it doesent work on iphone. I would like a quick shot without a big ui i have to include

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is a quick and easy way to do it

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
      var startY;
      function loadJs(){
        document.getElementById("upDownInput").onmousedown = startMoveUpDown;
      }      

      function startMoveUpDown(e){
        startY = e.clientY;
        document.onmousemove = moveUpDown;
        document.onmouseup = endMoveUpDown;
      }

      function moveUpDown(e){
        var input = document.getElementById("upDownInput");
        var moveChange = Math.ceil(e.clientY - startY);        
        input.value = moveChange;
      }

      function endMoveUpDown(){
        document.onmousemove = null;
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body onload='loadJs()'>
    <input style='margin-top: 200px' value='0' type='number' id='upDownInput'/>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: that one works, but it doesen't work on iphone, see: http://spacetrace.de/js/input_slider_test.html

Comment: I believe safari has a native ontouch listener like mozilla does (moztouch) but I am not sure, mouse and touch events are similar enough that they act the same way for most applications but for some things (especially multi-touch) you need an explicit touch handler.

Comment: ^ But if you are familiar with javascript you can easily incorporate touch listeners by checking for them first and then defaulting to mouse events when all else fails

Comment: i improved the script a bit on http://spacetrace.de/js/input_slider_test.html and now it works already ;) thx a lot for the start, i think this will be a great function for our space browsergame http://www.spacetrace.org

Answer (score 0):

You might want to checkout [jQuery UI's slider](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#rangemin) for a reliable, cross-browser slider.

Comment: What about [jQuery mobile's slider](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/forms/slider/index.html)? That ought to work

Comment: no, doesen't do the trick ;) i need the mouse movement in no extra space